# Http.post request from flutter client side doesn't send the request body to the server end

Tags: flutter, dart

This is my code to send the request body to the server side.However, I am receiving the requestbody as empty({}) in the server end.

```
String bodyF =
          jsonEncode({"countryCode": "91", "phoneNumber": phoneValue});
      final response = await http.post(
        Uri.parse('http://localhost:8080/twilio-sms/send-otp'),
        // headers: <String, String>{
        //   'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        //   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
        // },
        body: bodyF,
      );
```

I have also tried adding the headers(the commented lines), it has not made any difference. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

`body` is an object type, you can just send the Map as the body parameter. Try sending it without encoding. Encoding will convert it into a string.

```
final response = await http.post(
    Uri.parse('http://localhost:8080/twilio-sms/send-otp'),
    body: {"countryCode": "91", "phoneNumber": phoneValue},
  );
```

Comment: I have tried that too, had the same problem.

Comment: Have you tried sending a request from another client (such as Postman) and see if it works? @JSnow

Comment: Yes, It is working from postman and also from my react client end.